# Asynchronous call confirmation dialog in event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I want to return a boolean value from a jQuery confirmation dialog and return that value to an event (to either continue or stop default execution of an event). I know about asynchronous calls but I really can't get around this. This is what I have until now:

```
function moveConfirmation() {   

    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $('#dialog-move-confirm').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Move Separately': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                defer.resolve(true);
            },
            'Move Together': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                defer.resolve(false);
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                defer.resolve(false);
            }
        }
    });
    return defer.promise();
}

scheduler.attachEvent('onBeforeEventChanged', function(id, ev) {

    // if move contemporaneous exams, alert user to choose if move together or separately
    var state = scheduler.getState();
    var saveEvent = false;      

    if (state.drag_mode === 'move') {   
        moveConfirmation().then(function(move) {
            saveEvent = move;           
        });
    }
    return saveEvent;
}
```

What is happening is that saveEvent is still false and returning before the promise. What should I do? I also tried another promise.. but it still comes back to the same thing. Anyone sees a workaround for this?

Comment: You should understand that `return saveEvent;` is executed immediately, while `saveEvent = move;` - only "in future" (when deferred is resolved)

Comment: i understood that.... i just can't think of how I can return the value :<

Comment: What is ```scheduler```? I think it all depends on whether or not ```attachEvent``` allows asynchronous listeners.

Comment: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_onbeforeeventchanged_event.html .. its this api im using for a calendar.. hmm so I should ask if they support asynch listeners?

Comment: @Bernice did you see first comment (and response to it) in docs' page? Response for comment actually answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must know that the return statement within `onBeforeEventChanged` will always return false, since `moveConfirmation().then(...)` is async.

You will probably have to always cancel the `onBeforeEventChanged` event like you are doing, but rather than simply setting `saveEvent = move;` within the `moveConfirmation` handler, you will have to re-trigger the attempted operation programmatically in case the user wanted to proceed (perhaps using [`updateEvent`](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_updateevent.html)).

Please also note that you need a mechanism in place to avoid having the re-triggering process to invoke your dialog box again (e.g. if `onBeforeEventChanged` is fired when calling `updateEvent`).

EDIT: Note that you can also do the opposite if it looks better on the UI, always accept event changes, but undo them if needed as per the `moveConfirmation`'s response.

Comment: hmm thanks for your answer @plalx.. the only problem with this is that the event moves back to its place once I return false. So there is no way of knowing where the event was moved.. and even so, it would look ugly to the user :(

Comment: @Bernice Well, knowing where the event was moved would be easy since you only have to store that information before returning false, however I agree that it would look ugly. Perhaps you could do the opposite? Let the change happen, but revert it if needed? UI-wise it would be better that way I believe.

Comment: yes, that worked.. i defaulted it to return true and used `scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeEventChanged", function(ev, e, is_new, ev_old)` to update event with old start and end dates and refresh the view :) thanks for your idea :)